# How to display the line of object detection using cv2.minEnclosing circle

Tags: python, opencv

Hi Im knew in python and open CV.. I try to detect the object using circle

```
for a in cnts:
(x,y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(a)
center = (int(x), int(y))
radius = int(radius)
if area > 500:
    cv2.circle(img, center, radius, (0,0,255),1)
```

Is there any body know how to draw line of diameter on the circle?and display the size

Thank U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diameter:

```
cv2.line(img, (x - radius, y), (x + radius, y), (0,0,255),1)
```

Text: cv2.putText

Comment: Hi..Thank You Nuzhny.. I Change to this from your explanation..many thanks:                                                          cv2.line(img, (int(x), int(y)), (int(x + radius), int(y)) ,(0,0,255),2)                      cv2.line(img, (int(x), int(y)), (int(x - radius), int(y)), (0, 0, 255), 2)